# populating select list with common column names b/w two tabels via subquery -oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery

My code is clear enough to describe what i am trying to achieve

```
 SELECT  (select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name='tbl1'
    intersect
    select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name='tbl2')
```

```
    FROM   tbl2;
```

It is throwing `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I understand this error but don't know the alternate solution to achieve my goal .

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why is the inner select (`select ... intersect select ...`) not delivering what you want and you nest it within another select?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the subquery here. Try this instead:

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'tbl1'
INTERSECT SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'tbl2'
```

This will return a list of column names that exist in both `tbl1` and `tbl2`.

Comment: I know this but i  need to use the common column names in my select list (outer one) .
I am trying to avoid to type >30 column names manually . Maybe u can get an idea now as to why i am using subquery !

Comment: If you're trying to get a variable number of columns in the `SELECT`, that's not something you can do with straight SQL - in Oracle or any other database. In Oracle the solution would be to write a procedure that executes my query, uses the results to build a query string, and executes the query string using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.